# Batch-file get return Value from exe

Tags: windows, batch-file, return, return-value

I wrote a simple c-program DOW.exe, the return value is the day of week. I need this for my batchfile, so how can i do this, how can i get the return value ?

DOW.exe: Tu

my batchfile (doesn't work):

```
set day = DOW.exe

echo = %day%
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If, as seems, the `dow.exe` file echoes to console (stdout from the program) the day of week as text, then:

From command line

```
for /f %a in ('dow.exe') do set "dow=%a"
```

For usage inside a batch file, percent signs need to be escaped

```
for /f %%a in ('dow.exe') do set "dow=%%a"
```

What it does is execute the indicated command, retrieve its output and for each line in it, execute the code after the `do` clause, with the line retrieved stored inside the `for` replaceable parameter (`%%a` in this case)

Answer (score 8):

Use `%ERRORLEVEL%`. Like `echo %ERRORLEVEL`.

Comment: that returns a number like 2686742