# Cannot redirect the output of an OCaml bytecode to a file in Windows server

Tags: php, ocaml, windows-server-2012-r2

I have written a basic OCaml file `test.ml`, and compiled that my Windows server. It works in a command prompt:

[image]

However, if I run it in a php, **Only** the last line (i.e., `testbat.bat`) succeeded to write to `result.txt`, whereas `test.exe` always failed:

```
exec('C:\\PRODSERVER\\OCamlTest\\test.exe >> C:/inetpub/testaddbbacom/test/result.txt');
exec('C:/PRODSERVER/OCamlTest/test.exe >> C:/inetpub/testaddbbacom/test/result.txt');
exec('C:\PRODSERVER\OCamlTest\test.exe >> C:/inetpub/testaddbbacom/test/result.txt');
exec("C:\\PRODSERVER\\OCamlTest\\test.exe >> C:/inetpub/testaddbbacom/test/result.txt");
exec('C:/PRODSERVER/OCamlTest/testbat.bat >> C:/inetpub/testaddbbacom/test/result.txt');
```

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: I have found the solution: add `-custom` as option of `ocamlc` while compiling... I will not delete this question, which could be served as a record...

Comment: you can provide an answer to your own question, and even accept it. If the answer is useful, people will thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution: add `-custom` as option of ocamlc while compiling...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the solution described here: [Batch-file get return Value from exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732738/batch-file-get-return-value-from-exe) ?

Could be an issue with the output type used by the exe. Due to the first line of you .txt file, I think the program written successfully on it ... with an empty value.